# How to make ImageSwitcher fitxy like ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, imageswitcher

I want to add multiple photos so I used `ImageSwitcher`.
But I want the image to Fit the layout width and height, I tried fitxy like `ImageView` but it didn't work is there any way to do it?

```
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in xml, put `ImageView` with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` inside `ImageSwitcher`. If you want to set scaleType, set it to those `ImageView`s.

If you are using in code, then set LayoutParams to the `ImageView` with `ViewGroup.MATCH_PARENT` in your `ViewFactory`, then `ImageView.setScaleType()` if you want.